# SQL Server connection failing with LinqToSQL but working with EF 6

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have an application (.NET WPF LinqtoSQL) that works when I connect to a local database. When I changed to a database on a different server I get an error (SQL Server Instance not found error 26).

The solutions to this error are all based on the server, firewall, and making sure SQL Server Browser is up and running, none of which I can do because I have no rights on the server.

But I created a small test application using WPF and EF (ADO.NET) that successfully connects to the exact same database (and table). I have no clue what might be going on, but I am not sure I want to re-write the application using EF (at least right now).

Does anyone understand the difference between the framesworks' connection method to point me to a possible solution for the LinqToSQL version beyond waiting for the IT guys to "fix" the server?

Comment: Is the SQL Server using an multi-subnet Availability Group or Failover Cluster Instance?  Is the L2S project .NET 3.5?  L2S and EF both use ADO.NET (SqlConnection) to connect, so there is no difference between the connection strings.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft   The L2S and EF project are both .NET 4.5.2.  Something strange is afoot though as my Application.OnStartup override is not getting called as I've added some elements to the EF test.  So I am trying to track that down for now.  Thank you for verifying the SqlConnection is the same, that helps me move on.

Answer (score 0):

Given the revelation above that EF and L2S use the same connection class I figured a new project that points to the new server would fix my issue.  And it did:

I created a new project, added a new L2S item, and then copied in all of my old projects views/ viewmodels/ etc. and it runs just fine.

I thought I could simply update the connection string, as this is what I believe I have done successfully in the past, but perhaps there is something else had to be set somewhere in the project settings or generated DataContext code to the new server.  If anyone knows what that is please answer and I'll accept it.